# How to define shortcuts using the mac 'command' key in aquamacs (or emacs)

Tags: macos, emacs, command, shortcut, aquamacs

How can I define an aquamacs keyboard shortcut using the mac command key. I'd like 'command'-k  to act like ctrl-k (kill line).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "A-k") 'kill-line)
```

Then you can either press C-x C-e with the pointer at the end of this line to make the command active, or you can save the file and re-start emacs.